# Usability battles: designers vs. developers

Tags: usability

We develop for web.

For some reason our design team hates [the look of] indented unordered and ordered lists. This is the default treatment for these lists, and I think it's for good reason. These types of lists are generally important, and indenting them draws attention to them, and makes them easier to read.

Every web app we build that has content management is sure to use lists, and I always get demands to remove the indenting on these lists. I try to ignore these requests as long as possible, but eventually design wins the battle.

The design team also hates when vertical navigation in a tree structure has sub-levels that are indented. They prefer to use colour, font size, font weight or other treatments to indicate different levels in the tree. But again, indenting has to be removed.

These examples both seem to be absolutely terrible ideas in my opinion - but that's the problem - it's just my opinion. Without doing a full usability test (which most of our projects cannot afford), how can I determine what is the best usage? Since it's coming from design it seems that they carry more weight for usability because it's usally 'visual', not the developer implementing the designs.

I guess the questions here are:

1. Am I off base in thinking these are bad ideas? Can someone point me towards a study on this so I'm not relying on opinion? It's a little tough to search for this on the web. I tried Jakob Nielsen with no luck.
2. In the absense of a usability expert on your team, and in the absense of usability testing, how can a developer push back against design treatments that seem to represent poor usability?

Comment: Of interest?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165985/resources-to-create-applications-with-a-great-user-experience

Comment: This sounds like a good question for [a certain Stack Exchange site](http://ui.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: So, books eh? That sounds like reading. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I have no particular opinion either way, but I'd just like to point out that asking "how can I win these battles?" might not obtain you the most accurate information, just the information in your favor. :)

Comment: @Lambert - fair point, but in asking the question I'm quite willing to accept being wrong here. Currently it's one opinion vs another opinion, so if loads of people agree with one way or the other then it's clear. Or, if someone can point me towards some research to substantiate this, even better!

Comment: @In silico. Again, another stack exchange site that I didn't know about. I really with the SO people didn't open up so many sites with so much overlap. I'd rather not spend time figuring out the proper site to post to, sign up for it, etc etc.

Comment: @Insilico no it doesn't. It sounds like a perfect question to be closed as "subjective and argumentative", though.

Comment: This *definitely* belongs on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). I think it follows the guidelines for a subjective question. Stack Overflow is just the wrong forum. (It looks like it will be closed as "subjective and argumentative", but if that happens, I suggest reposting on the more appropriate sister site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I agree that indentation should be used in lists and menus.  However, I don't think you're doing yourself any favors by arguing repeatedly.  Someone has authority in your company and I wouldn't recommend arguing about the same thing once a decision is made.  If the designers have authority over whether or not to indent, and they say not to indent, then suck it up and stop arguing.

and find something else to fight over that they haven't already dictated a standard for.  :-)

Comment: There are piles of good links on SO about usability. This is just a grumpy post, really. +1 for suck it up.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that developers are hired for their expertise in programming while designers are hired for their expertise in making things look really really good.

The two skills are fundamentally different.  I'm sure there are decisions you make in the actual programming that the designers have absolutely no expertise in.  People do better at what they specialize in.

Comment: Looking good vs. working well are sometimes mutually exclusive. My job is not just to make things work, but to work well.

Comment: Agreed, but you're referring to visual appeal in this case, which is entirely a front-end design goal and not a programming goal.  If you really want to push the issue, I suggest a hallway usability test.  Let your users be the mediating party.